# What is the best way ( performance wise ) to animate numbers?

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive

In my angular.js app i'm using this directive:

```
https://github.com/sparkalow/angular-count-to
```

Which works great on the web.

When i compile it for phonegap, it's really really slow.

But what other way i have to animate a number from 0 to 200 (for example), in two secods, without hurting the performance of my app?

Comment: I would use a directive and avoid any methods that cause a digest, and update the element directly rather than relying on the digest cycle to update the counter. The plugin you linked to appears to be causing a digest cycle every 30ms. O.o

Comment: Do you know any directive that does not do a digest like crazy?

Comment: Nope. but, it wouldn't be too hard to build one. (i won't)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directive uses `$timeout`, as is the suggested way to get `setTimeout` functionality in Angular. It's likely doing this for one of the following reasons, though there are others too:

1. Easy to inject a mock for testing
2. Assumes that each step should allow other components to update
3. It's the "Angular Way"

I don't believe #2 is actually a big concern since it doesn't expose the value or update anything on the scope anyway, and does standard HTML `textContent` manipulation.

Regardless, the point is that `$timeout` does a `setTimeout` as well as a `$digest` (allowing Angular to update other components). The extra digest cycles are likely the slow part, and every Angular developer should read up on them as they're central to Angular's design (hint: [go read up on these now](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle)). As such, taking the original library, replacing the `$timeout` with a `setTimeout` call (and, optionally, a manual digest trigger when it finishes, in the `if (step >= steps)` block) should speed it up.

Be careful about these sorts of changes, though - `$timeout` is typically the correct way to go.